# Can't add marker saved as an EMF to the style manager

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, import, emf, style-manager

I'm trying to add a marker I created in PowerPoint and saved as an EMF to ArcMap. The current questions all state that all I have to do is open the style manager and go to the marker symbols folder, and add my new symbol there. However it won't give me the option to add a new symbol as this option is un-clickable. I'm not sure why. Any thoughts?